# Selecting only max column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select only a max column by grade_level. If I select a column that is less than max column by grade_level should not be selected.

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
name VARCHAR(50),
grade_level INT,
money INT
);

INSERT INTO sample (name, grade_level, money) VALUES       
("John", 1, 100),
("John", 2, 200),
("John", 2, 250),
("Shadow", 1, 110),
("Shadow", 2, 300);

SELECT * FROM sample;

name | grade_level | money
 John     1           100
 John     2           200
 John     2           250
 Shadow   1           110
 Shadow   2           300
```

This is my sample query so far while working on it.

```
SELECT name
     , max(money) 
  FROM sample
WHERE grade_level = (SELECT max(grade_level) FROM sample WHERE grade_level = 2)
GROUP BY name;
```

Output:

```
name | money
 John    250
 Shadow  110
```

As you can see here if I put `grade_level` as `2` in my `WHERE CLAUSE` it gives me a right value. But how can avoid selecting other column if I put `grade_level` as `1` because I'm only selecting the max column.

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which is likely to prove problematic in due course.

Comment: And I think you're confused about the difference between a row and a column. What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Something simple like this will work :

```
select name, max(money)
from sample
group by grade_level
```

Use grade_level in GROUP BY clause instead of name

Answer (score 0):

i think this what you are expecting let me know if i am wrong

```
SELECT name, max(money),grade_level FROM sample
GROUP BY name,grade_level;
```

i created a fiddle for your answer check it out : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48022b/4

**EDIT :**

try this :

```
SELECT name, max(money) FROM sample
WHERE grade_level = (SELECT max(grade_level) FROM sample)
and grade_level = 2
GROUP BY name;
```

check the fiddle for more info http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48022b/11

Comment: I wanted only to select the max column `max(money)` by `max(grade_level)` which I did. I'm just having a problem when selecting less than `max(grade_level)` should give a empty selected row

Comment: as i can see you are expecting value only for `grade_level = 2` and you are expecting empty set for `grade_level = 1` if tats what you are expecting check my updated answer